# inverse problem about scalar multiplication on koblitz curves (or more exactly the secp256k1)

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography, elliptic-functions, elliptic-operators

My problem is given $Q=nP$ to find point $P$ given 257 bits long integer $n$ and point $Q$.
[It’s something possible on other curves](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8925) but Koblitz curves have extra characteristic and can’t be converted to Montgomery or Edwards curves.
`P` is a fixed point while `n` and thus `Q` can vary leading to several examples using the same unknown `P`.

So is such operation possible on the `secp256k1` curve given a 237 bits integer `n` ? If yes, how to actually compute it in full ?

Comment: @Moo : it would be a duplicate of the first question without giving the answer for `secp256k1`.

Answer (score -1):

You can basically change  $Q = n * P$  into:  $P = Q / n$

which can be calculated as  $P = Q * (1/n)$

where $1/n$ can be calculated as the modular inverse of n modulo the group order.

see [here](http://rawcdn.githack.com/nlitsme/bitcoinexplainer/0a90433630d4ec0b159fd4eb36b97cc949301e8d/calculator.html#MS8xMjM0NTY3ODkxMjM0NTY3ODkxMjM0NTY3ODkxMjM0NTY3ODkKUD1HKjEyMzQ1Njc4OTEyMzQ1Njc4OTEyMzQ1Njc4OTEyMzQ1Njc4OQpQLzEyMzQ1Njc4OTEyMzQ1Njc4OTEyMzQ1Njc4OTEyMzQ1Njc4OQpQKjB4OWQ4YmM4YWUzMDRkMTk1ODQ5ZTIxNzNjOTZmZTM4NmM4ZjlhYjUxYTYxNzNhZjQ0YjFlN2QzMjVjODg5ZGI4Nwo=)  for an example.

in the example:

$1/123456789123456789123456789123456789$ (mod grouporder) == $0x9d8bc8ae304d195849e2173c96fe386c8f9ab51a6173af44b1e7d325c889db87$

calculate P:

$P=G*123456789123456789123456789123456789$

the inverse calculation:

$P/123456789123456789123456789123456789 ==     P*0x9d8bc8ae304d195849e2173c96fe386c8f9ab51a6173af44b1e7d325c889db87$

Comment: `n` is a known integer used in scalar multiplication and not a point… Are your sure it’s possible to compute it’s inverse ?